# The sequence of integer numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

How many sequences of positive integer numbers $\{a_n\}$ such that $$a_0 =1, a_1 = 2,|a_{n+2}a_n - a_{n+1}^2| = 1 ?$$

Comment: What is $b_n $?

Answer (score 1):

Ambiguous question.

Define the rational numbers
$$ b_n = \frac{a_{n+1} + a_{n-1}}{a_n}.  $$
IF we always have the constant $C$ with
$$ a_n a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}^2 = C,  $$
then a simple calculation shows that
$$ \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} = 1, $$ so that we have a constant $\tau$ with
$$  \frac{a_{n+1} + a_{n-1}}{a_n} = \tau,$$
or
$$ a_{n+2} = \tau a_{n+1} - a_n. $$
This is an ordinary linear recurrence, solutions easy enough.

HOWEVER,
 if $ a_n a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}^2 = (-1)^{z_n},  $ for some integer sequence $z_n,$ there are infinitely many possibilities.

AT LEAST, IT appears that way at first glance. It is also possible that, whichever way we start, $1,2,3,4,5,$ or $1,2,5,13, 34,$ is the way we must continue forever, in which case there are exactly two solutions. More work required. The person who asked should pursue this.

IT NOW seems the other answer is exactly correct. Either consecutive numbers, or Fibonacci numbers, or alternate Fibonacci, or the $c_{n+2} = 2 c_{n+1 } + 2 c_n$ from the other answer.

The hint for beginning a proof is just that, with $a_{n-1} > 2,$ it is not possible for both 
$$ \frac{a_n^2 - 1}{a_{n-1}} $$ and
$$ \frac{a_n^2 + 1}{a_{n-1}} $$
to be integers. That is, once $a_3$ and $a_4$ are chosen and legal, the rest of the sequence is forced by the condition of remaining integers.  The four sequences begin
$$ 1, 2, 3, 4,  $$
$$ 1, 2, 3, 5,  $$
$$ 1, 2, 5, 12,  $$
$$ 1, 2, 5, 13,  $$

Comment: @ Will Jagy: Thank you so much for your solution. I like your method very much. But I have a small question: Can you prove that the number of sequences $\{z_n\}$ (in the last of your solution) are infinite?

Answer (score 0):

By using the rule given above, we can compute the first few terms of such sequences. It is easily seen that there are at most four sequences of integers which satisfy the conditions.

From looking at the first five terms, my guess is that these can be given in the following ways:
$a_n=n+1$,

$b_{n+2}=b_{n+1}+b_n$ (Fibonacci sequence),

$c_{n+2}=2c_{n+1}+c_n$,

$d_{n+2}=2d_{n+1}+\sum_{i=0}^n d_n$

It remains to be verified that these sequences satisfy the given conditions.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much.